# Wrong character from a file downloaded

Tags: android, encoding, character

I am reading in my application a file on internet : [this one](http://webdfd.mines-ales.fr/cybema/cgi-bin/cgiempt.exe?TYPE=planning_txt&DATEDEBUT=20170424&DATEFIN=20170424&TYPECLE=evcleunik&VALCLE=5917)

But, when I try to show some of the text, I get wrong character on accent. (the app show � instead of "é" or "à" for example)

I'm using an AsyncTask and a BufferReader to read the file. What can I do to read it correctly ?

Here is the method I use to read the file from internet :

```
private List<String> allLine = new ArrayList<String>();

private void readListWEBDFD() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                allLine.add(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the InputStreamReader might be defaulting to ASCII. There is a constructor that takes two arguments where you can declare a charset like so:

```
new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help.